# C++ unique_ptr and polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism, unique-ptr

Maybe there is the same question but I haven't found it.

I have following code:

```
class MBase {
    public:
        ~MBase() { cout << "Base destructor\n" << endl; }
};

class MF: public MBase {
    public:
        ~MF() { cout << "MF Destructor" << endl; }
};

class MS: public MBase {
    public:
        ~MS() { cout << "MS Destructor" << endl;}
};

int main() {

    unique_ptr<MBase> ptr1 = unique_ptr<MF>(new MF());
    unique_ptr<MBase> ptr2 = unique_ptr<MS>(new MS());

    return 0;
}
```

And there is output

```
Base destructor

Base destructor
```

Isn't it right? Why derived destructors weren't called? What I have to do to fix that?

Comment: when using polymorphism and inheritance in C++, you should have a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymorphism in C++ requires virtual destructor, so that it would be possible to delete an instance
of derived class via a pointer to the base class object.

Long story short - allways declare destructors virtual if class is supposed to be derived from.

[When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

Answer (score 0):

when using polymorphism and inheritance in C++, you should have a virtual destructor